# making a column right to left direction

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and in this table I have a column which is used for arabic texts. However in the column the text are in left to right direction. Is it possible to make them rtl direction?

Comment: You didn't specify *where* you're viewing this data and *what* program/application you wish to have it displaying RTL. Is it a browser, some SQL GUI, MySQL CLI etc?

Comment: Can you dig up the table/database encodings, etc, and update the post with that info?

Answer (score 3):

There's the `REVERSE()` function. Here's the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_reverse) entry.

This function is **multi-byte safe**, which means it's safe for every character set / encoding.

```
SELECT REVERSE('abc');
```

results in

```
cba
```

To make it permanent you can update your column like this:

```
UPDATE yourTable SET yourColumn = REVERSE(yourColumn)
```

Comment: This is epic.  Well done.

Comment: @DaveS. Feel free to upvote, which is by the way the usual way to say thanks here ;) Or were you sarcastic? Did I get the question wrong?

Comment: Your answer is both valid and highly unusual.  I admit I was being sarcastic at first, but after thinking some more, it's totally valid.  It's probably not what the OP was hoping for, but hey, who am I to judge that.  The root problem is probably a character set/encoding issue, but reverse() probably would work at least as a short term thing.

Comment: @DaveS. Will update the question. But I don't get what's so "unusual" about my answer.

Comment: Nothing intrinsically, just I had interpreted the question to be an issue with collation character sets, and so from that perspective your answer almost seemed flip, but in a beautifully subtle way.  Sort of like Laurence Olivier saying to Dustin Hoffman "Try acting dear boy".